# Dividing double values and int values in one array in Python?

Tags: python

I have `h`, and `D`, of type `double` and `int`.

There are 5 `h` values for each `D`, and I put them in an array.

For `h` values that are integers, I did not append `.0`, e.g. 79 instead of 79.0

When I did division on this array, I get 79/50 = 1

For example,

```
h: 90.5 D: 45 h/d: 2.01111111111
h: 90.3 D: 45 h/d: 2.00666666667
h: 90.3 D: 45 h/d: 2.00666666667
h: 90.2 D: 45 h/d: 2.00444444444
h: 90 D: 45 h/d: 2
h: 79.2 D: 50 h/d: 1.584
h: 79 D: 50 h/d: 1
h: 78.2 D: 50 h/d: 1.564
h: 78 D: 50 h/d: 1
h: 77.8 D: 50 h/d: 1.556
h: 69.5 D: 55 h/d: 1.26363636364
h: 69.2 D: 55 h/d: 1.25818181818
h: 68.9 D: 55 h/d: 1.25272727273
h: 68.7 D: 55 h/d: 1.24909090909
h: 69.2 D: 55 h/d: 1.25818181818
```

This is easily fixed when I replace 79 with 79.0.
However I am curious why this is happening.

```
arr = OrderedDict()
arr[40] = [[93.9, 95.3, 95.3, 93.2, 93.2], []]
arr[45] = [[90.5, 90.3, 90.3, 90.2, 90], []]
arr[50] = [[79.2, 79, 78.2, 78, 77.8], []]

for D in arr:
    v = arr[D]
    for h in v[0]:
        print "h:", h, "D:", D, "h/D:", h/D
        v[1].append(round(h/D, 3))
```

Comment: "I have h, and D, of type double and int.", "I did not append .0, e.g. 79 instead of 79.0". In that case, it looks like you are doing int/int, which would indeed give you 79/50=0.

Comment: I forgot about the fact that in the division of int by int, the result gets truncated. Please close the question. I apologize.